# How to remove a ViewPager item from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewpager

I am creating an App with ViewPager (with 2 String elements: Model Class: Title and Content). I have a floating action button and I want when pressing a specific button, to delete that item from Firebase & ViewPager.

I tried in MyAdapter Class to remove from the list my current item [ modelList.remove(position)] and in TravelNotes to create a method for delete from Firebase database reference.removeEventListener(this); but I don't know where to call it.

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Model> modelList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Model> modelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.modelList = modelList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter,container,false);

        TextView model_titlu = view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        TextView model_continut = view.findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
        FloatingActionButton fab_delete = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_delete);

        model_titlu.setText(modelList.get(position).getTitlu());
        model_continut.setText(modelList.get(position).getContinut());

        fab_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Model m = modelList.get(position);
                modelList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                //how to delete?
            }
        });


        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

```
public class TravelNotes extends AppCompatActivity implements IFirebaseLoadDone, ValueEventListener {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    IFirebaseLoadDone iFirebaseLoadDone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_data);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Movie");

    iFirebaseLoadDone = this;

    loadModel();

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true,new DepthPageTransformer());


    }

    private void loadModel() {
      databaseReference.addValueEventListener(this);
    }

    //where to use this method?
    private void delete(){
        databaseReference.removeValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<Model> modelList) {
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,modelList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadFailed(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot modelSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            modelList.add(modelSnapshot.getValue(Model.class));
        iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(modelList);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Could you please advice what should I change in the code for deleting a specific item from ViewPager & Firebase?

Comment: The typical pattern when using Firebase is to remove the item from the database first, then let the normal flow from Firebase refresh your UI. So in that case, you need to call your `delete` method from the `onClick` handler that you attach to `fab_delete`.

Comment: I tried, but I got a NPE, see below error message: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dissertation.personalTravelPlan.TravelNotes.onCreate(TravelNotes.java:45)

Comment: That seems like `fab_delete` has not been initialized.

Comment: I initialized the button, but my point is that probably the logic for deletion is not the good one :(

Comment: The error message is quite explicit, and says that you're calling `setOnClickListener` on a `FloatingActionButton` that is not initialized (`null`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what helped me, in MyAdapter Class:

```
        final ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
        TravelNotesActivity.databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "MyAdaptor :" + ds.getKey());
                    keyList.add(ds.getKey());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        fab_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             modelList.remove(position);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             TravelNotesActivity.databaseReference.child(keyList.get(position)).removeValue();
             keyList.remove(position);
            }
        });
```